# SQL: using AVG and MAX aggregate functions but still returning duplicates

Tags: sql, aggregate, ssms

I have a select statement that asks for 4 fields. One is a MAX(date_field), date type, where I want the latest date and the other is the AVG(dollars_field), float type, where I want the function to get the average of these $ amounts and return only one, grouped by their sales order, which is the first field of this query.

**The result comes back with duplicates, as shown below - I've tried distinct, grouping by differently but it still returns duplicates. What am I missing?**

```
SELECT 
      t1.Name AS [Sales Order No.]
    , t2.name AS [Account Name]
    , (SELECT MAX(t3.Export_Date)) AS [Last Date]  
    , (SELECT AVG(t4.volume_discount)) AS [Rebate AVG]
```

Then I have the FROM clause with joined tables, and the WHERE clause with some filters, and finally:

```
GROUP BY t1.Name, t4.volume_discount, t2.name, t3.Export_Date
```

This is what it returns:

```
Sales Order No. Account Name    Rebate AVG  Last Date
SO-001      Nova Account Inc    96.000000   2020-06-24
SO-002      Acme                534.000000  2020-06-29
SO-002      Acme                534.000000  2020-07-02
SO-002      Acme                534.000000  2020-09-30
SO-002      Acme                424.000000  2020-07-23
SO-003      New Account Co      1603.000000 2020-09-30
```

Ideally, the SO-002 row would show up once, with the latest date (MAX) and the AVG of all those rebate amounts.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using correlated query or sub query (one value for each row) thus you see "duplicates"
2. All you need is to use Group by t1.name, t2.name

```
SELECT
      t1.Name
    , t2.name
    , MAX(t3.Export_Date) as Export_Date
    , AVG(t4.volume_discount) as volume_discount
from
  t1
inner join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
...
Group by t1.name, t2.name
```

3. Better to logically split your query by sub queries using WITH clause
   so your "duplicates" need to be eliminated before join
   If you provide full query with data samples i can provide more precise answer

Comment: @Arkon88 thank you sir, this worked. I upvoted and appreciate your help. I had the aggregate functions inside a select statement and had to add those in the group by and that was throwing my results off but now it works just fine. Thanks again.